# Объект request. Формирование данных для вставки

Tags: php, http, form, symfony, request

Использую на проекте либу symfony/http-foundation.
Есть большая веб-форма для заполнения данными.
[image: типо того]

Заполненные данные надо писать в базу, а затем в этой же форме отображать, если есть данные по идентификатору.

В этой связи моих скилов хватило на следующее:

В этом методе я ловлю request, выдергиваю из него нужные мне данные. После этого формирую общий массив ключей. И на его основе итоговый общий массив, который в итоге уйдет на insert.

```
public function createArrayData() : array
{
        $data = [];
        $request = $this->request->request->all();

        $reasons = $this->request->request->get('reason');
        $comments = $this->request->request->get('comment');
        $actions = $this->request->request->get('action');
        $responsible_groups = $this->request->request->get('responsible_group');
        $responsibles = $this->request->request->get('responsible');
        $deadlines = $this->request->request->get('deadline');

        $bsKeys = array_merge($reasons, $comments, $actions, $responsible_groups, $responsibles, $deadlines);


        foreach ($bsKeys as $bsKey => $bsVal) {

            $keyBranchBsStandard = explode('_', $bsKey);

            $branch = $keyBranchBsStandard[0];
            $bs = $keyBranchBsStandard[1];
            $standard = $keyBranchBsStandard[2];

            $data[$bsKey]['date'] = $this->period;
            $data[$bsKey]['user_id'] = $this->user_id;
            $data[$bsKey]['branch'] = $branch;
            $data[$bsKey]['nri_bs_number'] = $bs;
            $data[$bsKey]['standard_type'] =  $standard;
            $data[$bsKey]['reason'] =  $reasons[$bsKey] ?? null;
            $data[$bsKey]['text'] = $comments[$bsKey] ?? null;
            $data[$bsKey]['action'] = $actions[$bsKey] ?? null;
            $data[$bsKey]['responsible_group'] = $responsible_groups[$bsKey] ?? null;
            $data[$bsKey]['responsible'] = $responsibles[$bsKey] ?? null;
            $data[$bsKey]['deadline'] = $deadlines[$bsKey] ?? null;
            $data[$bsKey]['comment_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            if ( 
                 ($data[$bsKey]['reason'] == null) and
                 ($data[$bsKey]['text'] == null) and
                 ($data[$bsKey]['action'] == null) and
                 ($data[$bsKey]['responsible_group'] == null) and
                 ($data[$bsKey]['responsible'] == null) and
                 ($data[$bsKey]['deadline'] == null) 
                )
                  unset ($data[$bsKey]);
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Как сказал выше, в форме у меня отображаются ранее внесенные данные и только что внесенные.

По итогу я пишу в базу все вместе и старое и новое. Это выглядит убого с точки зрения архитектуры, но до большего я не допер.

Все работало до того момента, пока строк в форме не стало слишком много. И сейчас у меня просто выпадают данные. То есть данные которые вношу в форму отсутствуют в request.

Надеюсь поможете советом!
Спасибо заранее

Comment: Слишком много данных - это превышен post_max_size? что значит: выпадают данные?

Comment: Может стоит использовать пагинацию? Показывать по 50 записей для редактирования, а для добавления записи показывать отдельную форму?

Comment: @Yakoffka ну то есть условно форма на 400 строк, и строки которые после 200 не попадают в request при отправке формы. причину сам пытаюсь понять...

Comment: @Yakoffka пагинация не совсем мой вариант, по причине того что люди работают с фильтрами по всему списку. а если я допустим 400 записей разобью на страницы по 50, это 9 страниц. Будет не очень удобно скакать по ним чтобы найти нужную запись...

Comment: ну не знаю. количество записей будет расти, и рано или поздно вы упретесь в ограничения, если этого еще не случилось. Думаю стоит подумать о изменении подхода. может для каждой записи приделать свою кнопку "сохранить"?

Comment: @Yakoffka подход с пагинацией более приемлемый. посоветуйте ресурсы или подход по реализации

Comment: миллионы их... и ни одного я не знаю настолько, чтобы советовать. Любой фронтэнд фрэймворк умеет это, наверное. Дело вкуса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы упёрлись в лимит по количеству входящих переменных [`max-input-vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars).

Скорее всего это значение стоит по умолчанию и равно 1000. Если в форме в одной строке 5 полей, то в запросе придёт 200 строк (5 * 200 = 1000).

> Если входных переменных больше, чем задано директивой, выбрасывается предупреждение `E_WARNING`, а все последующие переменные в запросе игнорируются.

Можно увеличить это значение, но учитывайте, что чем больше значение, тем выше вероятность хеш-коллизий. (т.е. значение какой-либо колонки может внезапно исчезнуть из своего места и заменить значение другой колонки другой строки).

Могу предложить несколько вариантов решения:

1. Постраничный вывод (она же пагинация). Выводите по несколько строк + в конце таблицы несколько пустых строк для добавления записей.
2. Постраничный вывод + отдельная страница для добавления записей.
3. Редактировать данные построчно. Каждая строка имееет кнопочку `сохранить`.
4. Использовать для отправки данных `javascript`, метод `POST` и тип содержимого (Content-Type) `application/json` (тогда в лимит количества входящих переменных не упрётесь, но можете упереться в лимит размера запроса и хэш-коллизии при парсинге JSON)
5. При изменении содержимого ячейки автоматически ajax-запросом посылать новое значение на сервер, добавление строки - в модальном окне с формой для строки.

Я бы комбинировал последний вариант и пагинацию.

Comment: мне тоже 5 вариант нравится. можно даже и без пагинации в этом случае, если она будет мешать бизнесу.

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам! Увеличение max_input_vars на моменте действительно решило мою проблему. В перспективе постараюсь переработать подход по Вашим рекомендациям)